# UIwebview receive memory warnings and crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi I am basically loading a webpage within my app and every time I open the webpage

my app crashes after it receives 2 memory warnings(didreceivememorywarning) of level 1 and last on is randomly level 1

and level 2 and finally app receive signal 0 and app crashes on the spot. can't we load just a single webpage

Comment: Does your app have a bunch of other stuff loaded?  Lots of data/images/sounds?  I know it's a pain, but when you receive those memory warnings, it's important to free up memory since an app _will_ crash when it runs out.

Answer (score -1):

You're running out of memory. Either your web page (and included images and such) is too huge, or your page contains javascript that is allocating too much memory, or something else in your app is using too much memory and the web page is just the straw that is breaking the camel's back.